# Извлечь список с нажатыми checkbox(JSP, Servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, checkbox

Есть JSP страница:

```
   <form method="POST" action="/contact/controller">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="create_list"/>
        <div>
            <table>
                <caption>Contacts</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach var="contact" items="${list}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${contact.id}</td>
                        <td>${contact.gender}</td>
                        <td>${contact.firstName}</td>
                        <td>${contact.lastName}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" id="${contact.id}" value="${contact.id}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Create list" id="createListButton"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Как получить список c id, на которых пользователей поставил галочку в checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать request.getParameter(), передав в качестве аргумента id checkbox'a. Вернёт "on" если галочка стоит, null если нет